# Form of line elements in curvilinear

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics

I've just started studying [this book](https://books.google.de/books/about/Curvature_of_Space_and_Time_with_an_Intr.html?id=6MQOEAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y). On page 5 of it, the following sentence has written:

> Generally speaking, when using curvilinear (e.g. polar, cylindrical, spherical) coordinates $(y^1,...,y^n)$ for the Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^n$  we should expect the line elements to take the form of $$ds^2 = \sum_{ij}g_{ij}dy^idy^j$$

I want to know why our expectations should be in this form? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: Do you know what this looks like in the the case you use Euclidean coordinates? Does that form meet your expectations?

Answer (score 1):

In physics (and math), we have the idea that the distance is given by

$$\begin{align} &\text{d}s = \|  \vec{v}  \|\text{d}t\\\\\implies &\text{d}s^2 = \|  \vec{v}  \|^2\text{d}t^2 \text{ .}\end{align}$$

The length of the velocity is measured by the dot product thus

$$ \begin{align}  &\text{d}s^2 = \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}\: \:\text{d}t^2 
\\\\\implies &\text{d}s^2= (v^i \mathbf{e}_i)\cdot(v^j \mathbf{e}_j) \: \text{d}t^2
\\\\\implies &\text{d}s^2 = (\mathbf{e}_i\cdot\mathbf{e}_j)v^i\:v^j \text{d}t^2
\\\\\implies &\text{d}s^2 = g_{ij}v^iv^j \: \text{d}t^2 \text{ .}\end{align}$$

Lastly, all we have to say is that for each coordinate we have that

$$ \text{d}y^k = v^k \: \text{d}t $$

therefore

$$ \text{d}s^2 = g_{ij}\: \text{d}y^i\text{d}y^j \text{ .} $$